# how to sum count sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How to total count?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SHP.id = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "New", 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SHP.id = 2 then 5 ELSE NULL END) as "Accepted"
from SHP
```

RESULT:

```
NEW  Accepted
 1       5
```

But I need a total count
result: `6`

Comment: `COUNT()` _counts_ non-null values. `SUM()` sums values.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and its expected result.

Comment: I edit my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this;

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 1 END) as New, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 5 END) as Accepted,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 1 
               WHEN id = 2 THEN 5 END) as Total
FROM SHP
```

This is exactly what the `CASE` statement should be used for, the logic is very simple. This will avoid having to perform multiple calculations on the same fields.

As a note, the value in your `THEN` statement isn't used in this instance at all, it's just doing a `COUNT` of the number rather than performing a `SUM`. I've also removed the `ELSE NULL` because this is what the `CASE` will do by default anyway.

If your intention was to `SUM` the values then do this;

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 1 END) as New, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 5 END) as Accepted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 1 
             WHEN id = 2 THEN 5 END) as Total
FROM SHP
```

**Example**

Assuming you have only two values in your database, 1 and 2, we can create test data like this;

```
CREATE TABLE #SHP (id int)
INSERT INTO #SHP (id)
VALUES (1),(2)
```

And use this query;

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 then 1 END) as New, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 2 then 5 END) as Accepted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 1 
             WHEN id = 2 THEN 5 END) as Total
FROM #SHP
```

Gives this result;

```
New     Accepted    Total
1       5           6
```

Comment: result total 2 but I need 6, 1+5 = 6

Comment: `SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 then 1 END) as New, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 2 then 5 END) as Accepted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 1 
             WHEN id = 2 THEN 5 END) as Total
FROM #SHP` its ok thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SHP.id = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) + 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SHP.id = 2 then 5 ELSE NULL END) as "Total"
from SHP
```

Comment: result total 2 but I need 6, 1+5 = 6

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your query into a subquery and do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(New) as New, Sum(Accepted) as Accepted, Sum(New + Accepted) as Total FROM
(SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SHP.id = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "New", 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SHP.id = 2 then 5 ELSE NULL END) as "Accepted"
from SHP) as SubQuery
```

That's if you don't want to duplicate doing the counts and just adding the two together.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Perhaps you need to use SUM instead of COUNT?

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
with s1 as(
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SHP.id = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "New" 
from SHP 
),s2 as
(
SELECT  
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SHP.id = 2 then 5 ELSE 0 END) as "Accepted"
from SHP 
)
select sum("New"+  "Accepted") from s1,s2
```

Comment: result total 2 but I need 6, 1+5 = 6